# How to remap alphanumerical keys?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, remapping, keys

I have a buggy keyboard in which my w,f,b,6,2 keys are not working. I want to remap those keys to some other combination of keys such that when I press I get the corresponding  alphanumerical character in text. For example

```
w -> Ctrl+t
6 -> Ctrl+9
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Thought about buying a new keyboard? ;)

Comment: yep, currently not in a good financial position, might have to wait a long time for the new keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to do it quite as easy as you suggested.

One way to handle your situation might be to [define a compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html#compose) and create an `~/.XCompose` file. These are some example lines in such a file:

```
<Multi_key> <v> <v> : "w" U0077
<Multi_key> <V> <V> : "W" U0057
<Multi_key> <3> <3> : "6" U0036
```

With that you can do for instance:

<kbd>Compose</kbd> followed by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> => W

<kbd>Compose</kbd> followed by <kbd>3</kbd> followed by <kbd>3</kbd> => 6

HTH

Comment: Thank you it worked :)